# How do I share javascript or css files among multiple .Net core web applications in the same solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So, We have 4 .Net core MVC Web application projects within a single solution. There are multiple css and js files which have been made as library and need to be shared among all those projects. What we have been doing is copy and paste the files every time we make changes to them, which is pretty impractical as we can often forget to copy them, and also it's tedious to copy them everytime into all the projects. Most solutions I've found online are:

1. Add those files as link in each project. Which doesn't work quite well with debugging as even if you specify the files to be copied to the link location during build, we often change the js files while the prorgram is being debugged and the file update is reflected in the browser. But in case of link, I have to rebuild the project every time we update the js and css files.
2. Host our own CDN. This doesn't again fit into our workflow of debugging and would like to avoid.
3. Using Shared Project feature, we can use js and css files among projects. This, I tried to search online to no avail.

How can we do this without either adding them as links or creating our own CDN?

Comment: have a look at this article https://dev.to/brgrz/create-a-library-with-angular-and-publish-it-to-github-package-registry-1pch

Comment: Doing this, we would have to first change in the other repository containing the scripts, then push that, only then can we debug it in our browser. We would like to avoid that.